# 'recordingStatusCallback' doesn't get triggered

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-twiml

In the next code everything goes as expected except **recordingStatusCallback** URL is never called when the record is available:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
   <Say>Before calling {{To}}</Say>
      <Dial                      
         recordingStatusCallbackMethod="POST"
         recordingStatusCallbackEvent="completed"
         record="true" 
         trim="trim-silence" 
         recordingStatusCallback="https://ourdomain.com/ourapp/twCallService/recordingStatusCallBack">
         <Number
            statusCallbackMethod="POST"
            statusCallbackEvent="completed"
            statusCallback="https://ourdomain.com/ourapp/twCallService/statusCallBack">
            {{To}}
         </Number>
      </Dial>
   <Say>After calling {{To}}</Say>
</Response>
```

Also "**trim-silence**" seems not to work.

¿Does somebody know what happens here?

Note that record atribute is properly set to true.

Thanks!